# defining new command to be used inside align environment

Tags: align

I cannot understand why the following code does not work.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}

\newcommand{\tempa}{\def\tempb{\min}&\tempb}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
    \tempa\\
    \tempa
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

======================== Solved!

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\newtoggle{constDefine}
\toggletrue{constDefine}

\makeatletter
\def\obj#1#2{%
    \global\toggletrue{constDefine}%
    \gdef\@obj{#1}%
    &\mathrlap{\@obj}\phantom{\@obj}\quad #2 \span%
}
\def\const#1{%
    \iftoggle{constDefine}{%
        \global\togglefalse{constDefine}%
        \\&\mathrlap{\text{\normalfont s.t.}}\hphantom{\@obj}\quad&#1%
    }{%
        ,\\&&#1%
    }%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \begin{alignedat}{5}
        \obj{\min}{x_1}
        \const{x_1 + 2x_2 - x_3 &\leq 1}
        \const{x_1 + 2x_2 &\leq 1}
        \const{x_1 &\leq 1}
    \end{alignedat}
\end{equation*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: please do not edit questions to add an answer it spoils the question/answer format of the site. It is OK to post your own answer but post it as an answer, not by editing the question.

Answer (score 1):

There are many things wrong with your approach.

1. The cells of `align*` are group limited, and so a `\def` will not carry to the other cells...a `\gdef` is required.
2. `\tempa` must be expanded or else the `align*` cannot *see* the `&` tab separators
3. Because of it's optional argument (I am guessing), you can't simply `\expandafter` past a `\\`.

Here is a way to accomplish something similar to what you were trying.  Ugly, no?  Obviously, don't do this.  There must be a better way to accomplish your goal.  What is it you are *really* trying to accomplish?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\newcommand{\tempa}{x\gdef\tempb{\min}&y\tempb}
\def\z{\\}
\begin{document}
\def\tmp{\begin{align*}}
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tmp
\expandafter\expandafter\expandafter\tempa
\expandafter\z\tempa
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your careful answer. I was trying to mimic the 'optidef' package, which makes it easier to type optimization problems, in a simpler way that I require.

Comment: + Can your answer be applied to the 'alignedat' environment as well?

Comment: I found that I could achieve the goal by using \global and \gdef. I uploaded the working code in my original question. Thanks!